# Is there a 'tuple' equivalent thing in common-lisp?

Tags: tuples, common-lisp

In my project I have a lot of coordinates to process, and in 2D situation I found that the construction of `(cons x y)` is faster than `(list x y)` and `(vector x y)`.

However, I have no idea how to extend `cons` to 3D or further because I found no things like `cons3`. Is there any solution for a fast `tuple` in common-lisp?

For illustration, I made the following tests:

```
* (time (loop repeat 10000 do (loop repeat 10000 collect (cons (random 10) (random 10)))))

Evaluation took:
  7.729 seconds of real time
  7.576000 seconds of total run time (7.564000 user, 0.012000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.068 seconds GC time, and 7.508 seconds non-GC time. ]
  98.02% CPU
  22,671,859,477 processor cycles
  3,200,156,768 bytes consed

NIL
* (time (loop repeat 10000 do (loop repeat 10000 collect (list (random 10) (random 10)))))

Evaluation took:
  8.308 seconds of real time
  8.096000 seconds of total run time (8.048000 user, 0.048000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.212 seconds GC time, and 7.884 seconds non-GC time. ]
  97.45% CPU
  24,372,206,280 processor cycles
  4,800,161,712 bytes consed

NIL
* (time (loop repeat 10000 do (loop repeat 10000 collect (vector (random 10) (random 10)))))

Evaluation took:
  8.460 seconds of real time
  8.172000 seconds of total run time (8.096000 user, 0.076000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.260 seconds GC time, and 7.912 seconds non-GC time. ]
  96.60% CPU
  24,815,721,033 processor cycles
  4,800,156,944 bytes consed

NIL
```

Comment: `(cons x (cons y z))`

Comment: @alfasin I have tried this, and the speed boost is very small.

Comment: @alfasin It saves only one cons than `list`.

Comment: What is the type and range of your coordinates?  Are they integer so that they can they be encoded into a single number using eg. `dpb`and `ldb`.

Comment: @TerjeD. Thank you for your advice, but I have float numbers.

Comment: Have you tried complex numbers? If you know you will stay in 2D space, this might be a convenient and fast solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using declarations and inline functions, structs may be made faster than both arrays and lists:

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (space 3)))

(print "Testing lists");
(terpri)

(time (loop repeat 10000 do
       (loop repeat 10000
        collect (list (random 1000.0)
                      (random 1000.0)
                      (random 1000.0)))))

(print "Testing arrays");
(terpri)

(declaim (inline make-pnt))
(defun make-pnt (&rest coords)
  (make-array 3 :element-type 'single-float :initial-contents coords))

(time (loop repeat 10000 do
       (loop repeat 10000
        collect (make-pnt (random 1000.0)
                          (random 1000.0)
                          (random 1000.0)))))

(print "Testing structs")
(terpri)

(declaim (inline new-point))
(defstruct (point 
         (:type (vector single-float))
         (:constructor new-point (x y z)))
  (x 0.0 :type single-float)
  (y 0.0 :type single-float)
  (z 0.0 :type single-float))

(time (loop repeat 10000 do 
       (loop repeat 10000
          collect (new-point (random 1000.0)
                             (random 1000.0)
                             (random 1000.0)))))


"Testing lists" 
Evaluation took:
  8.940 seconds of real time
  8.924558 seconds of total run time (8.588537 user, 0.336021 system)
  [ Run times consist of 1.109 seconds GC time, and 7.816 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.83% CPU
  23,841,394,328 processor cycles
  6,400,180,640 bytes consed


"Testing arrays" 
Evaluation took:
  8.154 seconds of real time
  8.140509 seconds of total run time (7.948497 user, 0.192012 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.724 seconds GC time, and 7.417 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.84% CPU
  21,743,874,280 processor cycles
  4,800,178,240 bytes consed


"Testing structs" 
Evaluation took:
  7.631 seconds of real time
  7.620476 seconds of total run time (7.432464 user, 0.188012 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.820 seconds GC time, and 6.801 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.86% CPU
  20,350,103,048 processor cycles
  4,800,179,360 bytes consed
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I think `(:type (vector single-float))` is the most important one.

Answer (score 6):

The general way to go about such data structures is to use `defstruct`. This is how you create data structures in Common Lisp. So, if you wanted to have a point in three-dimensional space, this is more or less what you would do:

```
(defstruct point-3d x y z)
```

Why is this better then array:

1. It names things properly.
2. It creates a bunch of useful stuff you'd be creating anyway, such as accessors, a function to test for whether some data is of this type, a function to construct objects of this type and some other goodies.
3. Typing is more elaborate then in arrays: you can specify the type for each slot separately.
4. Specialized printing function that can print your data nicely.

Why is this better then lists:

1. You can always ask a struct to behave as a list by doing something like:

---

```
(defstruct (point-3d (:type list)) x y z)
```

- All the same stuff as arrays.

---

## Optimization issues:

You should probably try to explore other alternatives. The difference between creating an array or a cons cell of equivalent memory imprint is not worth optimizing it. If you are facing a problem w/r to this particular operation, you should consider the task in general unmanageable. But really I think that techniques like object pooling, memoization and general caching should be tried first.

Another bullet point: you didn't tell the compiler to try to generate efficient code. You can tell the compiler to optimize for size, speed or debugging. You should really measure the performance after you specify what kind of optimization you are trying to pull out.

---

I've written a quick test to see what's the difference:

```
(defstruct point-3d
  (x 0 :type fixnum)
  (y 0 :type fixnum)
  (z 0 :type fixnum))

(defun test-struct ()
  (declare (optimize speed))
  (loop :repeat 1000000 :do
     (make-point-3d :x (random 10) :y (random 10) :y (random 10))))

(time (test-struct))

;; Evaluation took:
;;   0.061 seconds of real time
;;   0.060000 seconds of total run time (0.060000 user, 0.000000 system)
;;   98.36% CPU
;;   133,042,429 processor cycles
;;   47,988,448 bytes consed

(defun test-array ()
  (declare (optimize speed))
  (loop :repeat 1000000
     :for point :of-type (simple-array fixnum (3)) :=
     (make-array 3 :element-type 'fixnum) :do
     (setf (aref point 0) (random 10)
           (aref point 1) (random 10)
           (aref point 2) (random 10))))

(time (test-array))

;; Evaluation took:
;;   0.048 seconds of real time
;;   0.047000 seconds of total run time (0.046000 user, 0.001000 system)
;;   97.92% CPU
;;   104,386,166 processor cycles
;;   48,018,992 bytes consed
```

First version of my test came up biased because I forgot to run GC before the first test, so it got disadvantaged by having to reclaim memory left after the previous test. Now the numbers are more precise, and also show that there is practically no difference between using structs and arrays.

So, again, as per my previous suggestion: use object pooling, memoization, whatever other optimization technique you may think of. Optimizing here is a dead end.

Comment: (1) I have tried `defstruct` before, and it's slower than simple lists. The fastest way till now is `make-array` because an array requires one allocation each, but others requires more allocations. (2) I know how to do `(declare xxx)` things for optimization. And it's better if I use the best data structure.

Comment: The `defstruct` is much better for writing readable code, but is not a good choice for efficiency, which is most concerned in my project now. I hope that future compilers can do something for acceleration structs.

Comment: @SaltyEgg it depends on the implementation, how structs are represented in memory, but chances are that arrays and structs are just the same thing. Eventually, strucs may be more efficient if you supply type information and the compiler is able to find a tighter layout. In any case, if you encounter a problem at the level of creating arrays vs creating structs, your code isn't going to make it. But my gut feeling says that you should be optimizing something else to get it working.

Comment: I'll appreciate that if you can show me results of some tests using structs like those in my post.

Comment: So, the `array` is much more efficient. I do need to create a lot of these objects, so the pooling/memorization could not help.

Comment: @SaltyEgg I've added my tests and they show that the difference between arrays and structs in you case is next to none. I would guesstimate that the overhead in structs is due to the function call to the constructor, which does all the same thing the code does in the second case. They don't differ in memory footprint at all.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working with floating-point values, in which case `(make-array 3 :element-type 'single-float)` may be best.  This way, you can expect the floats to be stored unboxed (in most implementations).

Be sure to sprinkle liberally with `(declare (type (simple-array single-float (3))))`.

Comment: Yes, this may be the most suitable data structure. But how to efficiently build one array based on current values? Using `:initial-contents` is slow because an extra list has to be constructed first.

Comment: Yes, using `:initial-contents` is slow.  Use what wvxvw does in their answer: `(setf (aref ...`